# PHP User defined function not working properly

Tags: php, function

Heres my function:

```
function get_r($groupid) {
 if (!empty($groupid)) {     
  $groupid = explode(",", $groupid);
  $rto = array();
  $x=0;
  while (count($groupid,$ustaffid) > $x) {
   $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id='$groupid[$x]'");
   while ($get = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $rto[] = $get['groupname'];
   }
   $x++;
  }
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE ustaffid='$ustaffid'");
  $numofgroups = mysql_num_rows($q);
  if ($numofgroups == count($groupid) && count($groupid) > 1) {
   $rto = "All of my groups"; 
  } else {   
   $rto = implode(", ",$rto);
   return $rto;
  }
 }  
}
```

when I call function  I'm using this:

```
get_r($groupid);
```

What I'm trying to do is get the variable $rto from my function, I have supplied the function with the $groupid variable. $rto is returning empty.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1) Try `print_r($groupid)` to be sure it is set correctly. 2) I doubt you really mean to pass 2 arguments to `count()`. 3) `$ustaffid` isn't being set anywhere. 4) You're only returning from one branch of your final `if / then /else`. I'd set `$rto = array();` at the VERY beginning of the function and `return $rto;` at the VERY end. 5) No need for `$x` if you just use `foreach($groupid as $id)`. (This highlights how `$groupid` is poorly named as it serves both as a list of group ids and as an array of group ids, but never as a single group id.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foo=get_r($groupid);
echo $foo;
```

and:
[Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 exit points in your function:

```
  if ($numofgroups == count($groupid) && count($groupid) > 1) {
   $rto = "All of my groups"; 
  } else {   
   $rto = implode(", ",$rto);
   return $rto;   <---- here
  }
} <--- here (end of the function)
```

Only when that if clause evaluates to FALSE does $rto get returned. Otherwise execution falls out of the bottom of the function and returns nothing.

Add another return here:

```
  if ($numofgroups == count($groupid) && count($groupid) > 1) {
   $rto = "All of my groups"; 
   return $rot; <---
```

or just move the other return call to the bottom of the function, so it returns $rto regardless of how the if() turns out.

```
  if (...) {
       ...
  } else { 
      ...
  }
  return $rto;
```

Comment: Yeah, took me a bit to figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only time that something gets returned is when the following line fails:

```
if ($numofgroups == count($groupid) && count($groupid) > 1) {
```

So basically you won't get any result if you match all of your groups. You should replace the `return` to the last line of your function to circumvent this.

Answer (score 0):

The returned variable goes out of scope once the function is done.
Do it like this

```
$rto = get_r($groupid);
```

$rto is assigned the return value.

Also, you're not returning the value if the if block is `true`.

```
if ($numofgroups == count($groupid) && count($groupid) > 1) {
   $rto = "All of my groups"; 
     return $rto; //********** This <<
  } else {   
   $rto = implode(", ",$rto);
   return $rto;}
```